# Fail to return context and var to the html in django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to render context_dic and the current time to my html file(inherit form another html) But it doesn't work. Could anybody help me fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

This is my python file

```
def homepage(request):
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    list_list = List.objects.order_by('author')
    context_dict = {'Lists': list_list}
    return render(request, ('index.html',context_dict), {'current_date':now})
```

And here is my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>This is my base page.</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello.</p>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
{% block footer%}
<p>It is now {{current_date}}.</p>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

And index.html

```
{% extends "about.html"%}
{% block content %}
{% if lists %}
    <ul>
    {% for list in lists %}
        <li><a href="/List/{{ list.slug }}">{{list.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
<strong>There are no lists present.</strong>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My url is like this

```
url(r'^home',homepage),
```

Comment: Note, you don't actually need to send the date to the template - you can insert it directly by using the `{% now %}` template tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your render, the context is the argument you set to `{'current_date':now}`
so if you want both these values in your context you need to add them to the same dict. Do something like:

```
context_dict = {'Lists': list_list, 'current_date':now}
return render(request, 'index.html', context_dict)
```